# Current menu item class highlighting 2 menu items

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, less

My menu looks like this: <kbd>Home page</kbd> | <kbd>About us</kbd> | <kbd>Pricing</kbd> | <kbd>Contact</kbd>. The pricing item is a custom link: `home.local#home-pricing` and the <kbd>About us</kbd> and <kbd>Contact</kbd> are pointing to subpages.

The problem that I have is that on the static home page where I'm displaying the pricing section, both <kbd>Home page</kbd> and <kbd>Pricing</kbd> items are highlighted with the `current-menu-item` class.

My less:

```
.current-menu-item {
    a {
        @extend .btn;
        padding-left: $base-padding + 9px;
        padding-right: $base-padding + 9px;
    }
}

.btn {
    background: $yellow-color;
    border-radius: $base-radius;
    padding: $btn-padding;
    color: $purple-color;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: $base-padding * 2;
    font-family: $heading-font-family;
    font-size: $base-font-size + .500rem;
    border: 0;
    &:hover {
        color: $purple-color;
        text-decoration: underline;
        @include linear-gradient($yellow-color 50%, $darker-yellow-color);
    }
}
```

and my home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>    
        <?php get_template_part('templates/fb'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>

        <div id="home-about-us">
            ...
        </div><!-- #home-about-us -->
        <div id="home-pricing">
            ...
        </div><!-- #home-pricing -->
        <div id="home-news">
            ...
        </div><!-- #home-news -->
    </body>

    <?php get_template_part('templates/footer' ); ?>
</html>
```

Could you help me out to find a solution for this?

Comment: The server can not differentiate between those two - because the hash part is not send to the server in the first place, so all it sees in _both_ cases is a request for `/`. You will need a JS solution for this that checks this on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added in wordpress admin a home class for home page and pricing class for pricing section. After that I have fallowed the clues left by @CBroe and @sunil (thank you for your help) and wrote this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#menu-main li.pricing.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
   });

   $("#menu-main li.pricing").click(function(){
     $('#menu-main li.home.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
     $('#menu-main li.pricing').addClass('current-menu-item');
   });

   $("#menu-main li.home").click(function(){
     $('#menu-main li.pricing.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
     $('#menu-main li.home').addClass('current-menu-item');
   });
 });
</script>
```

Maybe this will help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript like when click on pricing menu then you can add active class in pricing menu and remove from Home page menu